# The probability of choosing items more than a specified number of times

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm working on a programming (Python) project at work, and I'm facing a problem of testing a stochastic function.

The function could have $3$ different outcomes (that I know in advance, say $\{a,b,c\}$) with uniform probability, and I want to check whether the distribution is really uniform.

I cannot run the function MANY times because of runtime considerations, so I'm limited to a few hundred runs.

As a first attempt, I created a test that runs the functions $300$ times and checks whether each outcome is achieved more than $75$ times. 
However, I don't know how to calculate the probability that this test would fail.

Stating the question in mathematical terms:
There are $300$ trials. In each trial one of three items $\{a,b,c\}$ is drawn with a probability of $1/3$. What is the probability that each item was drawn more than $75$ times?

In general, I would like to know that probability for arbitrary numbers, so:

There are $n$ trials. In each trial one of $m$ items $\{a_1, a_2, ... a_m\}$ is drawn with a probability of $1/m$. What is the probability that each item was drawn more than $k$ times (where $k \times m < n$)?

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate the probability of rare events, one can rely on *large deviations theory*. Whole treatises exist on the subject hence let me explain the parts of the theory relevant to *your* problem in the first case (300 draws, 3 possible outcomes, at least 75 draws from each outcome).

The object of interest is the *empirical measure* $L_n$ of a sample of size $n$, that is, for every possible result $x$, $L_n(x)$ is the (random) number of draws yielding the result $x$. Let $u$ denote the uniform measure on the set of results. When the draws are independent, the law of large numbers guarantees that $L_n\to u$ almost surely, that is, $L_n(x)\to\frac13$ for each $x$ in $\{a,b,c\}$.

Large deviations theory allows to estimate the probability that $L_n$ differs significantly from $u$, when $n\to\infty$. More specifically, there exists a functional $I$ such that $P[L_n\in A]\propto\mathrm e^{-nI(A)}$ for every suitable set $A$ of probability measures on $\{a,b,c\}$. (*Experts know that $\propto$ means in fact that $\frac1n$ times the logarithm of the LHS converges to $-I(A)$, and that even that is not really true since topology on the space of measures comes into play and convergence to $-I(A)$ should be replaced by bounds on the limsup and liminf involving $-I$ applied to the closure and to the interior of $A$.*)

Anyway... what is perhaps more interesting is that $I(A)=\inf\{I(m)\mid m\in A\}$ for some functional $I$ defined on the space of measures and that, in your context, $I(m)=H(m\mid u)$, where $H$, called the relative entropy, is defined by
$$
H(m\mid u)=-\sum_x\log\left(\frac{m(x)}{u(x)}\right)\,u(x).
$$
To estimate the probability of the (nearly 100% certain) event that $L_n(x)\geqslant tu(x)$ for every $x$, with $t\lt1$, one considers the (rare) event $A_t=\{m\mid\exists x,m(x)\leqslant tu(x)\}$. It is relatively easy to show that $I(A_t)$ is realized for each of the three measures $m_t$ such that $m_t(x)=tu(x)$ for some $x$ and $m_t$ is uniform on the rest of the space. Thus,
$$
P[L_n\in A_t]\approx\mathrm e^{-nH(m_t\mid u)}.
$$
Unless I am mistaken, for $n=300$ and $t=\frac34$, numerically,
$$
\mathrm e^{-H(m_{3/4}\mid u)}=3^{5/3}\cdot2^{-8/3},\qquad 
P[L_{300}\in A_{3/4}]\approx3^{500}\cdot2^{-800}\approx.00545.
$$
Thus, the probability that each item amongst three was drawn at least 75 times amongst 300 is of the order of $99.5\%$.
A final word of caution might be needed here: the order of magnitude is relevant, the precise value not so much.

This can be adapted to any alphabet of any size $m$ and to cases when the probable limit is not the uniform measure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyhon for the combinatorical calculations too. This program gives you the precise probability: http://pastebin.com/NSyWzbEZ